# Can't connect to VM in Azure using RDP

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have created a test lab in Azure utilizing the guides below:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41684

and

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24277.test-lab-guide-install-exchange-server-2013-on-the-windows-2012-r2-base-configuration.aspx#Step_4_Install_and_configure_EX1

I have a server named EX1 that's running Exchange. Last night I was able to connect to it just fine but this morning I am unable to connect to it via the Azure portal. Here is the error that I get: [image: Error when connecting to EX1]

The machine is Running as shown under status. I've tried resetting the remote desktop connection which didn't work. I switched the endpoints for Remote Desktop to 3389 for the public port but still can't get in. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the endpoints and re-creating them?

Comment: Yes - tried deleting the endpoints and re-creating them. Wasn't sure what to use for public port.